# gfortran: compiling 32-bit executable in 64-bit system

Tags: linux, fortran, 32bit-64bit, gfortran

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit), with Linux kernel 3.5.0-51-generic, on an AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5200+ ×2. I have GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2.

I'm trying to compile some code into a 32-bit executable. I've checked that all the needed libraries are installed on my system (I ran ldd on a program previously compiled on a 32-bit computer, and downloaded the missing packages). I tried running $ gfortran foo.f -m32 -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu, but I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgfortran.so when searching for -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgfortran.a when searching for -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libquadmath.so when searching for -lquadmath
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libquadmath.a when searching for -lquadmath
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7 and /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7.2 directories, and they are both empty.

Can you please help me solve this problem? I did my research but this was as far as I could get.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need the 32bit devel package. Install it from your distro repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 64-bit libraries `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/...` don't apply to your 32-bit compile. You need to install the multilib compiler packages (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers). For example:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran-multilib
```

Now `gfortran -m32 foo.f` should work.