# GDB: how to call functions with modified parameters during debugging

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, fortran, gdb, gfortran

Consider the following trivial Fortran program that adds two integers via a subroutine and prints the result:

```
      PROGRAM MAIN

      INTEGER I, J, SUM

      I = 1
      J = 1

      CALL ADD(I, J, SUM)

      WRITE(*,*) SUM

      END

      SUBROUTINE ADD(I, J, SUM)

      INTEGER I, J, SUM

      SUM = I + J

      END
```

Compiling via `gfortran -g -O0 gdb-mwe.f -o gdb-mwe` and running in the GNU Debugger, I want to call `ADD` from the debugger with modified input arguments right before the write output. Here's what happens:

```
Reading symbols from gdb-mwe...done.
(gdb) break 10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4007dd: file gdb-mwe.f, line 10.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/username/Documents/Fortran/gdb-mwe 

Breakpoint 1, MAIN__ () at gdb-mwe.f:10
10        WRITE(*,*) SUM
(gdb) p j = j+1
$2 = 2
(gdb) call add(i,j,sum)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040079a in add (
i=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>, 
j=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x2>, 
sum=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x2>)
at gdb-mwe.f:18
18        SUM = I + J
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(add) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

How do I get this right?

Comment: Looks like gdb's `call` command isn't aware of fortran's call-by-reference rules - it's using the values of a, b, and sum as the actual parameters, rather than their addresses. Try `call add(&i,&j,&sum)` instead.

Comment: Did try it, still getting the same error. GDB version is the latest on Ubuntu LTS (7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5)

Comment: Interesting, `call add(&i,&j,&sum)` works on i386, but fails on x86_64. Looks like gdb is calling `add` with the low-order 32 bits of the addresses of the variables, `0xffffda18` instead of `0x7fffffffda18`.

Comment: Should I file a bug report then?

Comment: I found this existing bug report [Bug 15208 - Accessing a variable passed to a subroutine after an inferior call is not possible](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15208) and I think it covers your bug. I don't know, offhand, what else can be done. Several of the gdb developers read Stack Overflow, and maybe they can give some advice.

Comment: Thank you. I should probably also note, that the same error occurs using Intel's Version `gdb-ia` of GDB, too (Version 2017 Update 4).

Comment: If you have an older version of the Intel compiler tools, you might want to try their `idb` debugger to see whether it can do calls correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the [open bugs](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15208) in gdb prevents doing this currently.

A possible workaround would be to debug a 32-bit version of the code. This results in some differences, but for simple debugging tasks it may be sufficient.

For intel fortran compilers, this requires only adding the -m32 flag (provided 32-bit libraries have been installed).

For gfortran it seems that installing the multilib package first is necessary, as show in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28338658/5600084).